# I need solution to widget map in flutter

Tags: flutter

I add a button to add a list of widget in my screen, like this:

```
List<Widget> timeWidget = [];

buildTime() {
setState(
  () {
    timeWidget.add(Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          HourScheduleItem(
            enabled: true,
            day: _day,
            onRemove: () {
              timeWidget.remove(data);
            },
            onChanged: (date, hour) {
              setState(
                () {
                  _day = date;
                  _hour = hour;
                  print(_hour);
                },
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  },
);
```

}

When a click onTap button `buildTime();`  the return is a constructor into Column in my screen:

```
  Column(children: timeWidget.map((data) {
            return data;
          }).toList()),
```

But when I choose an option in the next widget added, the option chosen is shown only in the first widget, I believe this must be due to the fact that it does not get an index?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXygZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This due to how states and widgets in the widget tree are linked together. The [flutter YouTube channel](https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc) has a great in depth explanation of this topic, but TL;DR flutter doesn't "know" which widget in the list you actually clicked on unless you give each widget a unique identifier to tell them apart!

In almost all cases, you can do this by adding a `key: UniqueKey()` parameter to the constructor of the widget you're putting in a list. In your case, you would pass it in to your `HourScheduleItem` which would then pass it into the `super()` constructor.